# keyboard/trackpad functionality on Acer Chromebook 14 with dual booted Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, chromebook

I recently purchased an Acer Chromebook 14 CB3-431-C6UD and using [this](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/howto/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux/) guide, I managed to successfully set up Ubuntu on a 64gb usb drive that I keep plugged in at all times.

However, since I have been able to boot Ubuntu (or get to the desktop, prior to the installation of the OS) I noticed the severely impaired functionality of the on board trackpad and keyboard or lack thereof regarding the latter.

While I have been able to find a fix for the trackpad issue, there seems to be no known solution for the keyboard one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try GalliumOS.  It is based on Ubuntu.  The keyboard on my Acer R11 Chromebook worked with Gallium.  (Unfortunately, sound did not work, but this is probably specific to the R11.)

https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility

You might also be able to install and boot a Gallium kernel on your existing Ubuntu installation, but I have never done this.

According to comments 30 and 31 on the below Ubuntu bug report, keyboard issues with the R11 were fixed on more recent Ubuntu 4.4 and 4.8 kernels.  However, this fix did not work for my R11.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1630238